# user defined type not defined in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

I am trying to connect my vb 6.0 application to the database , so i have declared my data base as `Dim dbStu as Database`,but while compiling it is giving me error **user defined type not defined** , i found on another thread that , i need to add the `Microsoft Active x Data Objects 2.8 for xp`.I have done that too.so now my doubt is am i doing this correct ? should i have to declare those data base variable in **form only ?**.Or is there anything that is causing the error

Comment: What kind of database you're trying to connect?

Comment: You don't need to declare your database in vb project
just declare a ADODB Connection and use it to retriev data

Comment: can you eloborate please ,i'm new to vb

Comment: Are you looking at DAO code samples (which might use `As Database`)? Look for ADO instead, for example as in Hossein's answer. DAO was replaced by ADO long ago and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

you must add a reference to    Microsoft Active x Data Objects 2.8 or later 
then  declare an **ADODB.Connection** and open it with proper **ConnectionString** value that specify your **database path** and if it has a password a **password** value
and then you can use this connection object to get data from your database or insert data to it

```
public cnn As ADODB.Connection
public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDataShape;DATA PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=    DatabasePath\DatabaseName.mdb ;Jet OLEDB:Database " 'Password= DataBasePassword ;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Select * from FZONE ", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```